# Stateprovider is not working in Cordova angularJS app

Tags: angularjs, cordova, angular-ui-router, hybrid-mobile-app, phonegap

I am developing an app using cordova and angularjs.
ng-route is working fine but when I am trying to use ui.router , it's not working.The view template is not rendering inside 
        
My app.js

```
    angular.module('helloApp', [
      'ngAnimate',
      'ngCookies',
      'ngResource',
      'ngRoute',
      'ngSanitize',
      'ngTouch',
     'ui.router'
   ])
   .config(function ($routeProvider, $stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider
    .state('home', {
        url: '/',
        templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
        controller: 'MainCtrl',
    })
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please share your code?

Comment: added app.js code

Answer (score -1):

try below lines.

```
 angular.module('helloApp', [
  'ngAnimate',
  'ngCookies',
  'ngResource',
  'ngRoute',
  'ngSanitize',
  'ngTouch',
 'ui.router'
```

])

```
 .config(function ($urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider) {
$stateProvider
.state('home', {
    url: '/',
    templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
    controller: 'MainCtrl'
});
```

})

Hope this helps:)